# Regex replace with repetitive capture

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to do the following:

**Capture**:

```
((.*) Common) \| (A, B, C)
```

**Replace with:**

```
$1 | H, I, J $2
```

**On a sql file that looks like:**

```
'varX Common | A, B, C', 'asdf',  'varY Common | A, B, C', 'sdfg', 'varZ Common | A, B, C', 'qwer'
```

The problem I am having is that the string captures fine if there is only one occurrence of the match, but captures more than intended when presented with the string I provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `((.*?) Common) \| (A, B, C)`.

`?` toggles `*` to be non-greedy. So instead of matching as much text as it can, it stops at the first match.

I'm assuming, based on the `$1`, that you're using a PCRE variant in Perl, PHP, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Yes, this is the PHP variant.  Unfortunately that didn't limit the captures the way intended, but it did get me closer.  Now it seems to be including the 'asdf' in the second occurence, and the 'sdfg' in occurence 3.

Comment: In my case, I was able to simply specify:
`(([a-zA-Z\s]*?) Common) \| (A, B, C)`
I would like to figure out how to properly capture the items within the quotes though

Comment: Your best bet is something like `[^']+?` to capture everything that's not a comment in that case.
Or alternatively, `'(.*?) Common` to specify you want the match bounded by a quote before it.